# How to ignore special characters when referencing a string in excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use vba to read client feedback and reference it to a set of keywords mapped to categories. However the problem I am having is that on occasion, clients  use special characters such as “ -^<* ‘ in their comments and this is breaking my code as soon as it hit such a string.
How  can I make my code ignore these special characters and keep moving down the rows to search for criteria? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use an encoder as used in a url encoding can solve your problem. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: How do you "search for criteria"? Do you compare the value of each cell individually by string comparison?

Comment: It is easy to do if you update your question with  a **specific list** of the characters you want to ignore.

Comment: This is one scenario where using RegEx seems to be fit, so you can filter only the characters you want, rather than trying to remove each possible new code breaking char. [replace-text-using-regex-in-excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490598/replace-text-using-regex-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

First place the data to be "cleaned-up" in column **A**, then run:

```
Sub Kleanup()
    Dim A As Range, aa As Range, L As Long, i As Long
    Dim CH As String, temp As String
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    For Each aa In Intersect(A, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If aa <> "" Then
            L = Len(aa)
            temp = ""
            For i = 1 To L
                CH = Mid(aa, i, 1)
                If CH Like "[A-Za-z0-9]" Then
                    temp = temp & CH
                End If
            Next i
            aa.Value = temp
        End If
    Next aa
End Sub
```

It will remove all characters except **0** through **9** and upper case letters and lower case letters.